# Custom 404 http error in web.config is suppressing 400 errors in API C# code

Tags: c#, api, iis, web-config

I am developing an API using C# and .net 4.5.2; The API methods can return a handled BadRequest error or OK with an object response as per the below example:

```
[Authorize]
[RoutePrefix("api/Test")]
public class TestController : ApiController
{
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("TestMethod")]
    public IHttpActionResult TestMethod()
    {
            MyProvider op = new MyProvider();
            var lstResults = new List<Result>();
            try
            {
                lstResults = op.TestMethod();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return BadRequest(ParseErrorMessage(ex.Message.ToString()));
            }
            return Ok(lstResults);            
    }
}
```

All errors are returned in a message object as below JSON:

```
{
  Message: "Username or password is incorrect!"
}
```

The above was working perfectly until we added the below new configuration to redirect all 404 errors to a custom page for security issues. Now anybody (more specifically a hacker) who tries to call the API randomly, will be redirected to a custom 404 error page instead of the original .NET 404 page.

Web.config:

```
<httpErrors errorMode="Custom" existingResponse="Replace">
  <remove statusCode="404"  />
  <error statusCode="404"  path="404.html"  responseMode="File"/>
</httpErrors>
```

The problem is:

BadRequest errors are not handled anymore as it was mentioned in the beginning, the custom JSON structure is not returned anymore, custom messages like "Username or password is incorrect!" are not taken into consideration, just the same simple text is always returned: **Bad Request** as per below screenshot:
[image]

The solution should be running on windows server 2016 IIS version 10.

How to solve the issue by keeping both working?

**Update:**

1. If I remove `existingResponse="Replace"`, the badrequest message is returned, but the 404 custom error is not working anymore as per below screenshot
   [image]
2. If I set `errorMode="Detailed"` the 404 custom error won't work anymore, and HTML description is returned for a bad request as you can see here:
   [image]

Comment: Can you show me your complete Custom Error Page Web.config? and you can also try to set errorMode to `Detailed`.

Comment: @samwu thanks for the reply; I set the errorMode to Detailed 404 but the custom .Net error was returned.  What is meant by Custom Error Page Web.config ?  <httpErrors> details in question are the whole configuration set in web.config

Comment: I couldn’t understand what your said clearly, the Detailed sends detailed error information back to the client. can you elaborate on your question again?

Comment: @samwu question updated with screenshots for each case.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using the below to solve the issue; Thus I won't mark it as the perfect answer since it didn't solve the above issue and I didn't know yet why the configuration did not work properly as excepted. So any answer that can solve the issue is more than welcomed, below is what worked as excepted for me:

1. Remove the httpErrors configuration from web.config
2. Use Global.asax file and add the below method to handle any error not handled in the API solution:

   protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
   try
   {
   try
   {
   Response.Filter = null;
   }
   catch { }

   ```
               Exception serverException = Server.GetLastError();
               //WebErrorHandler errorHandler = null;

               //Try to log the inner Exception since that's what
               //contains the 'real' error.
               if (serverException.InnerException != null)
                   serverException = serverException.InnerException;

               // Custom logging and notification for this application 
               //AppUtils.LogAndNotify(new WebErrorHandler(serverException));

               Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;
               string StockMessage =
                       "The Server Administrator has been notified and the error logged.<p>" +
                       "Please continue on by either clicking the back button or by returning to the home page.<p>";

               // Handle some stock errors that may require special error pages
               var HEx = serverException as HttpException;
               if (HEx != null)
               {
                   int HttpCode = HEx.GetHttpCode();
                   Server.ClearError();

                   if (HttpCode == 404) // Page Not Found 
                   {
                       Response.StatusCode = 404;
                       //Response.Write("Page not found; You've accessed an invalid page on this Web server. " + StockMessage);
                       Response.Redirect("404.html");
                       return;
                   }
               }

               Server.ClearError();
               Response.StatusCode = 500;
               // generate a custom error page
               Response.Write("Application Error; We're sorry, but an unhandled error occurred on the server." + StockMessage);
               return;

           }
           catch (Exception ex)
           {
               Server.ClearError();
               Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;
               Response.StatusCode = 500;
               Response.Write("Application Error Handler Failed; The application Error Handler failed with an exception.");

           }
       }
   ```

It worked like a charm:

1. user is redirected to 404.html custom page
2. Any 400 error is being thrown properly with the JSON format and proper message